# bitwise XOR of two bit pattern having diferent length

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, logic, numerical-methods

how two bit patterns can be XORed if they have different length e.g one bit pattern is 11000 and other is 11000000111111. I have to do bit comparison of bit patterns having length 5000 and 35000 so plz give me any formula or method to calculate it

Comment: AFAICT `11000` is equivalent to `011000` and `00000000011000`, but it depends on your notation system.

Comment: I want to do bit wise comparison  to identify which bits are matching

Comment: just to add to @defaultlocale 's answer: Python actually supports this natively

Answer (score 4):

As  default locale said, if we interpret both binary strings as binary numbers, the natural thing to do is to pad the shorter one on the left with zeros. The reason is that `1011`, as a binary number, is equal to `0001011`, for any number of zeros on the left.

But in general, the method of comparison will depend on what your bit strings represent. For example, you may think that the shorter string may be similar to a part of the longer one, but you don't know which part. (I think this is called a *registration problem*.) In this case you could extract parts of length `5000` from the longer string (with some offset $n$) and do `XOR` with the shorter one, searching for $n$ that gives the smallest number of mismatched bits.